# Custom Radio Buttons in Alert Dialog are never checked

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-radiobutton

I have a custom AlertDialog with radio buttons which will open on click of a textview. Everything is working as it is supposed to except that the radio buttons are never shown as "checked". Whenever I open the AlertDialog all of the buttons are unchecked. After selecting a button and opening the AlertDialog again the buttons are unchecked again.

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="15dp">

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rg_gender"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonMale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/therapist_male"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonFemale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/therapist_female"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonEither"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/therapist_either"
        />
</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

My AlertDialog:

```
private void therapistDialog() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gender_dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.show();

    final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rg_gender);
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId == R.id.buttonMale){
                tvGender.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.therapist_male));
                therapistSex = 0;
                mMassage.setTherapistSex(therapistSex);
                male.setChecked(true);
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.buttonFemale){
                tvGender.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.therapist_female));
                therapistSex = 1;
                mMassage.setTherapistSex(therapistSex);
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.buttonEither){
                tvGender.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.therapist_either));
                therapistSex = 2;
                mMassage.setTherapistSex(therapistSex);
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: First of all, consider using switch instead of  if else construction. I suppose that you are not storing your checked state. Try to bind you state to some data and ititialize your dialog with this data whed dialog is building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not restoring the state of dialog on opening and assign a new instance of `AlertDialog` every time You invoke `therapistDialog` method.
Try to check the button on `AlertDialog` view init.
Add

```
int buttonToCheck = mMassage.getTherapistSex();
RadioGroup radioGroup = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rg_gender);
int buttonId = radioGroup.getChildAt(buttonToCheck).getId();
radioGroup.check(radioGroup.getChildAt(buttonToCheck).getId());
```

Before invoking `dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);`

Comment: Thank you! This works! I only have one question. The buttonId is never used?

Comment: Not sure, what You are asking for. You already previously have used button id to know which checkbox was checked. Here, in method `setTherapistSex` You also saved only child order number, so to check the button You must first get 'RadioGroup' child by order number and not by button id.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured that out. Thank you one more time!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call the method `therapistDialog()` is creating a new instance of the alertDialogBuilder. You must create instance of the alertDialogBuilder only once globally,

and just call

`final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.show();` inside your method.

*note:* this is not tested but this should work and will maintain your check box states also